# How to Get GeoJSON Feature on Map.Locate in React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I am creating a map with imported GeoJSON data. I am trying to create a Find Me button that will zoom to the user's location and get a property associated with the enclosing region (as defined by the GeoJSON layer). I am able to get the property when the user clicks the map, but I can't figure out how to get the property when the map.locate() function is used.

I've tried adding a locationfound listener to the GeoJSON component using onEachRegion but it doesn't seem to fire. The 'locating' prop is a state set by the button to trigger the map.locate() function.

```
//...Imports

export const MapView: React.FC<{
    setRegion: any,
    locating: boolean,
    setLocating: any
}> = (props) => {

    const geoStyle = {
        fillOpacity: 0,
        weight: 0.5
    }

    const onEachRegion = (region: Feature, layer: L.Layer) => {
        const code = region.properties?.BCR;

        layer.on({
            click: (event: L.LeafletEvent) => {
                props.setRegion(code)
            }
        })

        layer.on({
            locationfound: (event: L.LeafletEvent) => {
                props.setRegion(code)
            }
        })
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <MapContainer center={[45, -95]} zoom={3} attributionControl={false} ref={setMapRef}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>
                        contributors'
                    url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <AttributionControl prefix={'Leaflet'}/>
                <GeoJSON
                    data={BCRData as GeoJsonObject}
                    style={geoStyle}
                    onEachFeature={onEachRegion}
                />
                <LocationMarker locating={props.locating} setLocating={props.setLocating} />
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
export const LocationMarker: React.FC<{
    locating: boolean,
    setLocating: any,
}> = (props) => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<LatLngExpression>([0,0]);
    const didMount = useRef(false);

    const icon = L.icon( {
        iconUrl: '/images/marker-icon.png',
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    });

    const map = useMapEvents({
        click(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng)
        },
        locationfound(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng)
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, 8)
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.locating) {
            map.locate()
            props.setLocating(false)
        }
    }, [props.locating]);

    return(
        <Marker position={position} icon={icon} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Turf.js to determine which region contained the user location.

```
export const getRegionContainingPoint = (point: number[]) => {
    let region = '';
    
    // Loop through geojson object and check if point is inside. Return region number
    turf.featureEach(BCRData as FeatureCollection, function (currentFeature, featureIndex) {
        
        let containsPt = false;
        // convert geometry collection to feature collection
        const flattenedCollection = turf.flatten(currentFeature);
        
        // loop through resulting collection
        turf.featureEach(flattenedCollection, function (flattenedFeature, flatIndex) {
            const ptInGeometry = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point, flattenedFeature);
            if (ptInGeometry) containsPt = true;
        })
        
        // get property value if point is found in feature
        if (containsPt) {
            const props = currentFeature.properties;
            if (props) {
                region = String(props['BCR']);
            }
        }
    })
    return region;
}
```